# NetLogo: How to export the mean value of a plot to BehaviourSpace directly?

Tags: netlogo

I was wondering if there is a way to add mean of a plot to BehaviourSpace measure , I was thinking to add that value to a list and then use the mean value of that list in my experiment, but I just wanted to double check if this is the only way I can do it.

I can use variable [] and update the value each tick  and export mean value of this variable as an output for my experiment. Any other suggestions are really welcomed:

```
set Gi lput Gini-v1 "Village1" Gi ; this is in go procedure 


to-report Mean-Gi ; this is for reporting at the end of each run 

  report Mean Gi
end
```

PS: Using  export plot I will get all the details, but considering 15 plots per experiment and more than 100 runs per experiment I am looking for an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you there thinking is the way to do it.

This is similar to your previous question, [NetLogo: Is there a way to customize CSV files generated by export-plot to only include certain columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246663/netlogo-is-there-a-way-to-customize-csv-files-generated-by-export-plot-to-only), in that it involves wanting to do something with the data in plots besides just have it end up on the screen.

It would be great if NetLogo allowed that, but it just doesn't — except from an extension.

When I said “an extension could do it” in response to your previous question, I should explain further that I wasn't imagining a "custom `export-plot` extension”, I was imagining a “primitives for pulling data out of plots” extension. If that extension existed, then it would provide the needed building blocks to do lots of things: pulling data out of plots in order to export it in a custom way, pulling data out of plots in order to do statistics on it (perhaps in order to include those statistics in BehaviorSpace results), and so on.