# Netlogo: export a single custom csv file from numerous plots

Tags: netlogo

I have a model that outputs 5 different plots. I will run the model 100 times and need one single csv file containing all results of one of the plots. Using behaviourSpace outputs 100 separated files with irrelevant data like "color", "pen down?", "current pen", etc. so merging and cleaning them is time-consuming. I have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246663/netlogo-is-there-a-way-to-customize-csv-files-generated-by-export-plot-to-only) that csv and array extensions can be used but don't know how to properly use them to solve this issue. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Presumably you are plotting some value. Let's call that value 'var1'. What you probably want to do is have 'var1' in the list of outputs in your BehaviorSpace setup.

Comment: How do I code in BehaviorSpace setup that 'var1' is an output?

Comment: In the 'Measure runs using these reporters' box, simply write the word `var1`. Have you read the documentation at https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html?